Is Laravel Regenerating Encrypted Session and XSRF-TOKEN on Each Request (Laravel 11)?
On our Laravel 11 application, the encrypted XSRF-TOKEN and laravel_session are regenerated and set on every request with different values. Is this expected?
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6IlpLZ05kNkdWNM2Nzg5YjY2MTE5OTY3MDgyNGNiIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 23 May 2024 14:36:13 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; secure; samesite=lax
set-cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IlpLZ05kNkdWNM2Nzg5YjY2MTE5OTY3MDgyNGNiIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Thu, 23 May 2024 14:36:13 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly; samesite=lax

This answer suggests it's normal due to the encryption and decryption of the cookie within Laravel.
Laravel cookie encryption
We wanted to check if it's still relevant in Laravel 11?

The XSRF Token does indeed change on every request, can't say I've look explicitly at the laravel_session value though.
